# changing color of h2

Tags: html

How I can change the color of h2 ?

I have tried `<h2 color="#006699">Process Report</h2>` but it's not changed and I am still getting this default black colour

Thanks .

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try CSS:

```
<h2 style="color:#069">Process Report</h2>
```

If you have more than one h2 tags which should have the same color add a style tag to the head tag like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
h2 {
    color:#069;
}
</style>
```

Comment: And when you start to try CSS, put it into an external stylesheet or into the `head` of the document, between `<style type="text/css"></style>` tags. Not in-line inside of the elements themselves.

Comment: There are some cases where inline styling will be better, but as a general practice @DavidThomas is right. The second block of code is preferable.

Comment: @rekire Your <style type="text/css">
 tag was really helpful

Answer (score 2):

If you **absolutely must** use HTML to give your text color, you have to use the (deprecated) [`<font>`-tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-FONT):

```
<h2><font color="#006699">Process Report</font></h2>
```

But otherwise, I strongly recommend you to do as [rekire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995926/rekire) said: **[use CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8684629/4830)**.

Comment: You might want to point out that [`<font>` is deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-FONT).

Comment: Wow, I haven't seen a `<font>` tag since the 90's.  Let's bring it back old-skool.

Comment: @Rocket: I know, but since the code in the question uses the color attribute I thought it might be a requirement. I just hope I don't get too many down votes for this...

Comment: I doubt he has a "requirement" to use outdated technology.  `<marquee><blink>I love HTML</blink></marquee>`  :-P

Comment: You're probably right, should I delete my answer?